# modbus tcp with king pigeon RTU5026

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I am a student and need some help for programming a simplest modbus tcp server to get values from a GSM/gprs device like RTU5026 or RTU5023 from king pigeon. This device supports communication with modbus RTU over tcp or modbus tcp. I think modbus tcp is that, what I need.

With this product is a small manual [manual](https://www.iot-solution.com/u_file/2012/file/30f59c698d.pdf). I think I found the most important information:

- modbus tcp is supported (and I enabled it with my own connection details to get a connection with the tcp server)
- register address: 0 (holds temperature)
- data type: 16 bit
- function code: 4

With the following python script, I get an established and holding registration, but I cant ask or poll the register address with the temperature. I think I need help for communcation AND modbus request.

- at first I got the Welcome Message after establishing, that is the IMEI - perfect
- second step is the request and reading, but the answer is still "?"
- every minute I get a heartbeat message "req" - perfect

```py
import socket
import sys
from thread import *

HOST = ''    # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 6655    # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ('Socket created')

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print ('Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1])
    sys.exit()
print ('Socket bind complete')

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print ('Socket now listening')

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    #Sending message to connected client
    conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n') #send only takes string
    
    #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
    while True:
        
        #Receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(15)
        print(data)
        #print('\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02'))
        #000100000006010300010001
        #000500000006010400000002
        conn.sendall('\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01')
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(100)
            print(data)
            conn.sendall('\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01')
        
        if not data:
            break
        
    #came out of loop
    conn.close()

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    
    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

after establishing:

```
<IMEI>
?
?
?
?


req
```

Comment: Not a great manual (but this is not unusual). Can you please edit the question and include the exact output (formatted as per the edit). Your request looks OK but I'd suggest removing the `conn.send('Welcome to...` and, perhaps, try sending an RTU request (asking the manufacturer for example code may be worthwhile; the manuals sometimes leave out important info...).